# which is better every user have a table or just a row

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, android-studio

I making android app part of it is that user will upload videos and inter some details and all this stuff and choose videos as favorite and found all videos he uploaded in one place , so which is better making for every user a table or just a row in a table

Comment: Users should be rows in tables.

Comment: Ok thanks @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a row for every user in a table. Details and other stuff should be in rows in other tables and then linked via primary key and foreign key.

If you create a table for every user it will take much space and not just that, you have to access a different table for every user, which makes it very complicated. In rows you can access a single user by the primary key of the corresponding row.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not really the place to ask primarly opinion-based questions.